# Command Blocks with preset commands

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been trying to `/give` myself a command block with a preset text for about an hour or so (playing on Windows 10). My current attempt is as follows:

```
/give @p stone 1 0 {"can_place_on":{"blocks":["dirt","glass"]}}
```

So far that is all I have been able to do as of the time I posted this for help.
I hope somebody could assist me with fixing it, or a simple fix like replacing the command with something else.

Comment: The answer you mentioned is outdated. New JSON components have been added since and those are used mainly for map making as they allow blocks to be placed on specific other blocks only while in the gamemode adventure. (Oh, and thank you for linking that second link.)

Comment: Those "new JSON components ... alow[ing] blocks to be placed on specific other blocks only while in the gamemode adventure" are actually mentioned in the answer to the linked question.

Comment: What new JSON components are there?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to give yourself an item with a preset name/text, but what you can use instead is a contraption that makes a dropper drop the renamed item then ./tp the item to a player